# How can I input 16 bit number in assembly language in microprocessor 8086?

Tags: assembly

I want to move that number in CX(counter register).
And it's not possible to move al into Cx.

Comment: AL is not 16 bits anyway so it wouldn't really help. Anyway could you give some more context to this?

Comment: AL is 8bits and CX is 16bit, so you could use `MOVZX`

Comment: I want to get the input from user and store it in counter register so loop can run according to the input..
I know there are other ways I can use instead of loop.
But I only want to use loop..
Is there any way to store it in Cx?

Comment: You need to read a number symbol by symbol, convert each symbol to the corresponding digit (i.e. '9' to 9) and make a number out of the digits (i.e. 1, 2, 4 to 124). On documentation there is something about this.

Comment: @programmer: the [LOOP instruction is slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742570/why-is-the-loop-instruction-slow-couldnt-intel-have-implemented-it-efficiently).  Compilers never use it, so I'd recommend just looping a different way, if you want to learn to read compiler output.  LOOP is useful when optimizing for code-size at the expense of speed, though, but it sounds like not in this case because it will take you extra instructions to set up for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can move `al` into `cl` and then zero out `ch`:

```
mov cl,al
xor ch,ch
```

Comment: I'd prefer `xor cx, cx` / `mov cl, al`.  That pattern still works for 32-bit registers where you can't zero the upper halves separately.  It also avoids partial-register stalls on Intel P6-family microarchitectures.